# Given a modified binary search tree, find k'th smallest element

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose in a given binary tree **if each node contains number of child elements**, then what is the optimal way to find k'th smallest element in the tree ?

Please note this is not regular BST. Each node is containing number of child element under it.

Comment: Absolutely not a homework. @Skizz, I would like to show you my office badge for once. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find_element(root, k)

    if(root.left.nchildren + 1 == k - 1) 
        return root;

    if(root.left.nchildren + 1 >= k)
        return find_element(root.left, k)             

    else 
        return find_element(root.right, k - (root.left.children + 1))
```

Comment: @ajeet, Simone: `each node contains number of child elements`. this includes the right subtree. if you are looking for the nth element in a full binary tree with n elements, this algorithm will wrongly return the root.

Comment: @amit, Observe that Simone is counting left.nchildren not root.nchildren. And Simone is counting K starting from 0. Considering that his algo will return right result.

Comment: @ajeet: Simone edited the answer after I made the comment, and this issue  was indeed solved by counting the left son size instead the root size. My comment is not relevant anymore

Comment: @amit : Got it amit. :) Also in that case, the answer I had posted within the gap of 30second was indeed the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
find (root, k)
{
leftChildCount = root->left->n
rightChildCount = root->right->n

if (leftChildCount+1 == k)
  Print root node
else if (k< leftChildCount)
  Find(root->left,k)
else
  Find(root->right,k-leftChildCount)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse BST in [InOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486039/in-order-tree-traversal) traverse manner and store elements to array. Your array is a sorted array.